# How can I do this with Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, laravel-relations

I'm working on an Online Store project and I wanted to create **Add To Favourite** system for users to add products that they like to their favourite list.

So I have created a table named `favourite_products` which goes like this:

[image]

So the `usr_id` stands for user id and `prd_id` stands for product id.

Here is the `User.php` Model:

```
public function favourites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'favourite_products', 'usr_id', 'prd_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

And this the `Product.php` Model:

```
public function favouritees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favourite_products', 'prd_id', 'usr_id');
    }
```

Now I wanted to get all the data from this table.

So I tried adding this to the Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $favouriteProducts = FavouriteProduct::all();
        return view('admin.shop.favourites.all', compact('favouriteProducts'));
    }
```

Then in the Blade:

```
@foreach($favouriteProducts as $fav_pro)
    @php
        $member_info = \App\User::where($fav_pro->usr_id)->first();
        $product_info = \App\Shop\Product::find($fav_pro->prd_id);
    @endphp 
    <tr class="closest-tr">
        <td>{{ ++$menuCounter }}</td>
        <td>{{ $member_info->usr_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product_info->prd_name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

But I wanted to know that, how can I retrieve `usr_name` & `prd_name` by User and Product Models relationships? Therefore, I won't need to add the Model names in the view and get data there...

I tried these two at the Controller, but these are both wrong:

```
Product::whereHas('favouritees')->get(); // if two different users add same product, it returns only one of them

User::whereHas('favourites')->get(); // if a user add different products, it returns only one of them for the user
```

So the question is, how can I show all the results from `favourite_products` at a table with User or Product Many To Many relationship?

Comment: As you can see, everything always have an elegant simple solution with laravel.

Comment: @N69S Laravel is awesome dude :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the data (product and users that favorite that product) get all the product with the users related to them

```
$products = Product::whereHas('favouritees')->with('favouritees')->get(); 
// if two different users add same product, it returns only one of them but it will have two users in the relation favouritees
```

Then in you blade you can loop them

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @foreach($product->favouritees as $user)    
        <tr class="closest-tr">
            <td>{{ ++$menuCounter }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->usr_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->prd_name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the pivot model, you can add these relations in your `FavouriteProduct` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'usr_id');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'prd_id');
}
```

now in your blade file:

```php
@foreach($favouriteProducts as $fav_pro)
    <tr class="closest-tr">
        <td>{{ ++$menuCounter }}</td>
        <td>{{ $fav_pro->user->usr_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $fav_pro->product->prd_name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

also don't forget to add `with` to your query in your controller

```
public function index()
{
    $favouriteProducts = FavouriteProduct::with('product', 'user')->all();
    return view('admin.shop.favourites.all', compact('favouriteProducts'));
}
```